# Ubuntu Studio 22.04 USB stick failing to mount volume

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I've downloaded ubuntustudio-22.04.1-dvd-amd64.iso from https://ubuntustudio.org/download/ .

sha256sums:

- Reference checksum (online): 3fe6fa9a17fa7a4b34b2ec7ff3b9500d354ca644aedcc37096b923f14247f504
- Checksum from the download: 3fe6fa9a17fa7a4b34b2ec7ff3b9500d354ca644aedcc37096b923f14247f504

AFAICS the download is intact.

I used unetbootin to create a bootable USB. The machine successfully loaded the GRUB menu from the USB stick, but "Try or Install Ubuntu Studio" failed with the famous "Invalid argument; doesn't fit into 512 byte sector yadda yadda; mount /dev/loop0 failed" error.

I saw many threads about problems with physical USB media causing this error. So I ordered another USB stick, brand new, and tried again.

Same error.

My research turned up two reasons why this could happen: 1/ bad download; 2/ bad media. sha256sum fully rules out the first. The second, since I've tried a completely brand new, previously unopened USB stick, seems unlikely.

I have also disabled secure boot before the last couple attempts.

The machine is a ThinkBook 14 btw. Lenovo has generally been good for Linux installation. I've been through 14.04, 16.04, 18.04, 20.04 and never seen this.

So what do I do next?

Thanks.
hjh

Comment: I suggest that you try with another tool in order to create a USB boot drive, and I would recommend in Windows: [Rufus](https://rufus.ie) or a cloning tool for example [Balena Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) and in another Ubuntu: the **Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator** or more generally in Linux: **Disks** (`gnome-disks') or [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb). -- If still problems, please tell us about your computer: details about the model in order to give us more clues to what could be the problem.

Comment: Thank you, I might not have time *today* to try this but within the next couple of days.

Comment: Solved -- Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator succeeded where unetbootin failed. Thanks!

Comment: Congratulations and thanks for sharing your solution :-)